# UE4 C++, FWidgetRenderer::DrawWindow

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

Пытаюсь перенести плагин MeshWidget с версии 4.23 на 4.25.

есть переменная типа FWidgetRenderer, в этом классе есть много определений одной функции DrawWindow([docs.unrealengine](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/UMG/Slate/FWidgetRenderer/index.html)), но почему то не хочет брать ту самую а берёт самую первую, все аргументы правильные.

что то можно сделать в этой ситуации?
Пробовал каст, не помогает

Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.cyberforum.ru/unreal-engine/thread2945804.html
Эта ссылка на мой ответ я всё смог читай и самый нижний ответ там всё расписано

Answer (score -1):

HitTestGrid.ToSharedRef().Get()

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]